# How to identify random id and call it as child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to identify random id and call it as child? I need to call this id in the excerpt:

```
favoritosRef = firebaseRef.child("favoritos").child( idUser )
```

[image]

```
favoritosRef = firebaseRef.child("favoritos").child( idUsuario );
    valueEventListenerFavoritos = favoritosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            perfil.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Perfil perfil2 = dados.getValue(Perfil.class);
                perfil.add(perfil2);
            }
            adapterPerfil.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to call these ids that I did in number here:
firebaseRef.child ("bookmarks"). child (idUsuario) .child (here call the id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting anything because you are using `getChildren()` only once. To solve this, you need to loop twice like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("favoritos").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Perfil> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Perfil perfil = ds.getValue(Perfil.class);
                Log.d("TAG", perfil.getTitulo());
            }
        }

        //Set the list to adapter
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

If its the current user's ID you need, you can call:

```
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

then

```
            userID = user.getUid();
```

Or, if it's the random pushID that you need (the child of the userID), you need to save the pushID reference as a variable when it is it is first created:

```
DatabaseReference pushRef = databseRef.push();
String pushKey = pushRef.getKey();
```

So you can query it later..